# Transformation of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, control-theory

Consider the system:

$$
\begin{split}
\dot W &= i u(t)W(t)\\
\dot S &= e^{-rt}\sqrt{(1-u(t))W(t)}
\end{split}
$$

I would like to examine a system:
$$
\begin{split}
\dot x &= u(t)x(t)\\
\dot y &=\sqrt{(1-u(t))x(t)}
\end{split}
$$

Can someone tell me the transformations between $x(t)$ and $W(t)$, also between $y(t)$ and $S(t)$?

Comment: What is known about $i$ and $r$?

Comment: @Arastas these a positive constants (interest rates)!

Comment: Is $u(t)$ an external input? Why not directly solve the equation for W and then determine S by integrating the right-hand side of the second differential equation with W(t) plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x$ is only a function of $W(t)$, so $x(W(t))$. Differentiating this yields

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial W} \frac{dW}{dt} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial W} i\,u(t)\,W(t), \\
&= u(t)\,x(W(t)).
\end{align}

This can be simplified to

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial W} i\,W(t) = x(W(t)).
$$

This can be solved using [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables), which yields

$$
i\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dW}{W} \to \int i\frac{dx}{x} = \int \frac{dW}{W},
$$

$$
i\log(x) + c_1 = \log(W) \to c_2 = \frac{W}{x^i}.
$$

Choosing $c_2 = 1$ yields

$$
\boxed{
x(W) = W^{1/i} = \sqrt[i]{W} \Leftrightarrow W(x) = x^i
}.
$$

However I am not sure if there is a function for $y$ which is just a function of $S$, since $\dot{S}$ is a function of time and $W$, while $\dot{y}$ should be not a function of time, but is of $x$ instead of $W$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to find function $S(y,x)$? It doesnt need to depent only on y. this would solve my problem also.

Comment: @Damian the exponential term in time I think would also mean it should also be a function of time.

Comment: this would also be ok:)

Comment: I solved the second system with pontryagin-maximum-principle to compute reachable sets. so any transformation with known variables like y,x,t would be appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any particular reason why you would want to transform your differential equation. Why not solve it in the given formulation?

If $u(t)$ is a known input you can solve the first equation

$$\dfrac{dW}{W} = i u(t) dt \implies \ln |W|=\int_{t_0}^{t}iu(\tau)d \tau$$
$$\implies |W(t)| = \exp\left[ \int_{t_0}^{t}iu(\tau)d \tau\right]$$
$$\implies W(t) = \pm\exp\left[ \int_{t_0}^{t}iu(\tau)d \tau\right].$$

Then use this in the second differential equation and integrate the differential equation.

$$S(t)=\pm\int_{t_0}^{t}\exp(-r\tau)\sqrt{(1-u(\tau))W(\tau)}d\tau$$

Comment: u(t) is not known! i solved the second system by Pontryagin-Maximum-Principle so a transformation would be nice. Then i could just transform the results from the second system (for example reachable sets). but thanks anyway